# creating map not working

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, geoext, ext-js

am following this tuto to create a map on web with geoserver, GeoEXT, EXTJs, and openlayers      [here's the link](http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/apps/gaz/map.html)i downloaded ext 4.2.0, openlayers 2.12 and GeoEXT 1.1, when i try to show the map : //geo.ancfcc/geoserver/www/search/map.html , all i get is a blank page.
i don't know what's the error (i don't know where to find error log) 
here's my map.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
    <html>
     <head>
       <title>
        A map
       </title>
<script src="../ext/ext-all-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../ext/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../ext/ext-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ext/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script src="../openlayers/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../GeoExt/lib/GeoExt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../GeoExt/resources/css/geoext-all-debug.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
     Ext.onReady(function() {
      var map = new OpenLayers.Map();
      var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Blue Marble",
        "http://geo.ancfcc/geoserver/wms",
        {layers: "ancfcc:titres_salemed_valid"}
      );
      map.addLayer(layer);

      new GeoExt.MapPanel({
          renderTo: 'gxmap',
          height: 400,
          width: 600,
          map: map,
          title: 'A Simple GeoExt Map'
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That's not all your HTML I assume as there is no <body>. Could you include the body HTML as well? Also, seeing as you just get a blank map that normally points at a JavaScript error. You should load it up in Firefox and use the Firebug extension (Or Safari/Chrome - Developer Toos) to look at any errors returned in the console.

Comment: sii i have it, sorry just forgot to copy well : </head>
  <body>
    <div id='gxmap'></div>
  </body>
</html> 
ok thanks for the advice

Comment: Now it's works i can see the panel but i dont get the map inside. i assume it's a WMS issue, because when im trying to load this page : http://geo.ancfcc/geoserver/wms am getting this error: in serviceException report:
  <ServiceException code="MissingParameterValue" locator="request">
Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@90c029
</ServiceException>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't work because you have :

- Ext 4.2.0
- Openlayers 2.12
- GeoExt 1.1

and
if you carefully read http://geoext.org/tutorials/quickstart.html#getting-geoext you have

> Download the latest Ext 3.x from the ExtJS website

Furthermore, read http://blog.opengeo.org/tag/extjs4/ to confirm